# aws cli command for list of elastic ip address that are not in use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to write a shell script to find the list of Elastic ip address that are not in use by any instances and need to associate free ip to my newly launched instance.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Can you show what you've tried already and where you're having difficulties?  [ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this aws cli to get all the elastic Ip's that are not in use.

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[?NetworkInterfaceId == null ].PublicIp"
```

If you need output in text format just append `--output text` to the CLI.

You can then similarly use the cli to launch a new EC2. Refer the cli https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html on details around launching an instance.

Comment: Thanks yogesh for quick response.

Comment: Even i got another command too, that also works perfectly fine ( aws ec2 describe-addresses --output text --region ca-central-1 | grep -v 'i-' | cut -f9 )

Comment: I believe your command is not going to give you only un-assigned addresses